# Is there a way to search all the local and global variables for a value in javascript when a breakpoint is hit in devtools?

Tags: javascript, windows, google-chrome-devtools, firefox-developer-tools, ie-developer-tools

Is there a way to search all the local and global variables for a value in Javascript when a breakpoint is hit in devtools? For example, I know there's a value 'John Smith' held by some variable. I want to locate that variable. I don't know which variable it is. It would be nice if it can search through collections and arrays as well. 
Either a built-in feature in one of the browsers or a code snippet I can run.

Comment: Just look at the `Scope` section of the Dev tools for the value you are interested in and then you'll see the variable that holds it.

Comment: I have thousands of variables to go check manually.

Comment: For global variables u can use Object.keys( window ); :)

Comment: That's a list of variable names. What use is it going to be for if I am looking for a value?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, none of the DevTools allows to search a variable by its value, they only list the variables and properties grouped by their scope when the script execution is stopped.